# DjangoQ fails in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: django, migration, bitbucket-pipelines, django-q

I am creating a scheduled task with DjangoQ and to register it I have this code on my apps.py:
from django.apps import AppConfig

```
class ShiftsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'shifts'

    def ready(self):
        from django_q.models import Schedule

        func: str = 'path_to_func'
        schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(func=func).exists()
        if not schedule:
            Schedule.objects.create(func=func,
                                    hook='path_to_hook',
                                    schedule_type=Schedule.MINUTES,
                                    minutes=15,
                                    repeats=-1
                                    )
```

It's working fine locally.
Then, I wanted to deploy it and I have some pipeline steps being triggered on every commits. The steps are about linting and testing:

```
- step: &run-linter
    image: python:3.7
    name: Run linter
    caches:
      - pip
    script:
      - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings
      - export DB_NAME=django
      - export DB_USER=django
      - export DB_PASS=django
      - export DB_POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
      - pylint ./* > pylint_report.txt
    artifacts:
      - pylint_report.txt
- step: &run-test
    name: Run Test
    caches:
      - pip
    script:
      - export DB_NAME=django
      - export DB_USER=django
      - export DB_PASS=django
      - export DB_POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
      - coverage erase
      - coverage run manage.py test
      - coverage xml -i
    services:
      - postgres
    artifacts:
      - coverage.xml
```

But on the testing step when  I call coverage run manage.py test
I receive:

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 17, in
>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 419, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 395, in execute
> django.setup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24,
> in setup
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
> 122, in populate
> app_config.ready()   File "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/shifts/apps.py", line 11, in
> ready
> schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(func=func).exists()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 808, in exists
> return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
> line 559, in has_results
> return compiler.has_results()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1139, in has_results
> return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1169, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90,
> in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_q_schedule" does
> not exist LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_q_schedule" WHERE
> "django_q_s...

If I try to migrate before running the test I have the same error.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There traceback states that the exception takes place in `manage.py` at line 17; which refers to `coverage run manage.py test`.

I believe that you need to run `python manage.py migrate` before running the tests in order for the tables managed by djangoq to be created.

Are you sure that you get the same traceback when you migrate first?